# wpf datagrid is not displaying complete result?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

[image]

[image]

In the above images ,in console window i am having two hardware addresses and two ip addresses but datagrid is displaying only last result what would be the reason for this why datagrid is skipping one result?

Code is :

C#:

```
   public class IPMAC
        {
            public string ip { get; set; }
            public string mac { get; set; }



        }

   public ObservableCollection<IPMAC> ipmac { get; set; }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ipmac = new ObservableCollection<IPMAC>();
            this.DataContext = this;


        }
     var item = new IPMAC();
                string pattern = @"(F8-F7-D3-00\S+)";
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(stringData, pattern);





                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hardware Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
                   // ipmac.Add(new IPMAC() { mac = match.Groups[1].Value });

                    item.mac = match.Groups[1].Value;

                }
              //  ipmac.Add(item);

                string pattern2 = @"(192.168.1\S+)";
                MatchCollection matchesIP = Regex.Matches(stringData, pattern2);
                foreach (Match match in matchesIP)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IP Address : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
                   // ipmac.Add(new IPMAC() { ip = match.Groups[1].Value });

                    item.ip = match.Groups[1].Value;

                }
                ipmac.Add(item);

            }
            private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                dg.ItemsSource = ipmac;
            }
```

XAML is:

```
<DataGrid
                  Name="dg"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Height="250"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ipmac}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"            

                  IsReadOnly="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mac Addresses" Binding="{Binding Path=mac}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Addresses" Binding="{Binding Path=ip}"/>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You are adding only one data to the list

Comment: @Sajeetharan.. where?

Comment: where i need to add another data to the list ??

Comment: It is showing data in a grid multiple times but it is repeating the same values again and again !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the following: the string you use contains this part in it somewhere:

```
...
Hardware Address : F8- ...
Hardware Address : F8- ...
IP Address : 192...
IP Address : 192...
...
```

When you are parsing the string (`stringData`) you are only taking one match into consideration (the last one).

Fix it like this:

```
            string pattern = @"(F8-F7-D3-00\S+)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(stringData, pattern);

            string pattern2 = @"(192.168.1\S+)";
            Match matchIP = Regex.Match(stringData, pattern2);

            while (match.Success && matchIp.Success)
            {
                    var item = new IPMAC();
                    item.mac = match.Value;
                    item.ip = matchIP.Value;
                    ipmac.Add(item);

                    match= match.NextMatch();
                    matchIp = matchIp.NextMatch();
            }
```

Of course this code only works well if there are exactly the same number of matches for both patterns.